# Dotnetnuke register text editor (MVC)

Tags: model-view-controller, text, dotnetnuke

I'm developing a DotNetNuke MVC module based on Chris Hammond's templates.

Now I want to use the HTML rich text editor in my settings.cshtml page.

Normally, in my ascx file I would register the component like this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="TextEditor" Src="~/controls/TextEditor.ascx"%>
```

But I don't know how to do this now?
Can anyone help please?

Comment: I have a partial solution, but am in the process of getting advice from DNN Corp about this.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  I am in the same situation, however from what I know this is not possible.

Comment: Did you get any answer Jonah? Same situation here aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those people who are interested in the solution:
in your ascx add a declaration for the text editor, and then add an instance of the control i.e.

'< % @ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="TextEditor" Src="~/controls/TextEditor.ascx"% >'

' < dnn:texteditor id="txtContent" runat="server" height="200" width="500" / >'

In your web.config or 'admin tect editor' menu you can select the default html editor. In my case it was the CKEditor but off course you can use your own.